# Cannot use "." as separator in antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I am writing a parser to parse the string like `aaa.bb = "ccc@ddd.com"`

The antlr4 grammar file is like:

```
    DOT : [\-\_\.\@\>]+ ; 
    fragment CHAR: [a-zA-Z_0-9];
    fragment CHAR2:[\-\_\.\@];
    DECIMAL : '-'?[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)? ;
    ATTR_ID : CHAR+;
    VALUE_ID: ATTR_ID+ (CHAR2? ATTR_ID)*;
    attribute
    :
    (attrGroup DOT attrKey) | attrKey;
    value :  DECIMAL | VALUE_ID | DATE;
```

The question now is when I remove the `VALUE_ID` lexer def, the attribute can be parsed like:

```
attrGroup: aaa
attrKey: bbb
```

If I add back the `VALUE_ID` def, it gives me the error:

> attribute:1:0: mismatched 
>   input 'aaa.bb' expecting ATTR_ID

Note: it works if the input string is: `aaa>bbb = "ccc@ddd.com"`

Did I make any mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Parser rules for ValueID. This will allow the lexer to match ATTR_ID, but then determine that tokens should form a value_id

```
DECIMAL : '-'?[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)? ;
DOT : [\-\_\.\@\>]+ ;
ATTR_ID : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;


value_id: ATTR_ID+ (DOT? ATTR_ID)*;
```